# Add where clause to count and not entire query without using subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

The below query works but the "o.opendate is not null and o.orderdate is not null and o.closedate is null and o.canceldate is null" portion of the where clause needs to only apply to the orderID count (orderCount). Right now it is applying to the entire result set and that is not what I want. How can I change the query to do this? Also these tables are very large so I am relying heavily on indexes and trying not to use subquerys for performance reasons. Any help would be appreciated

```
select s.ZipCode, count(o.[OrderID]) orderCount, b.Longitude, b.Latitude, b.ordering 
from ZipCodeServiceAvailability s  
left join pdx_orders_view o on s.ZipCode = left(o.[ZipCode], 5)  
left join ZipCodeBoundaries b on s.ZipCode = b.ZipCode  
Where s.state = 'TX' and Ordering % 10 = 0 and 
     o.opendate is not null and o.orderdate is not null and o.closedate is null and o.canceldate is null  
Group By s.ZipCode, IsServiced, b.Longitude, b.Latitude, b.Ordering  
Order by s.ZipCode, b.Ordering
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a case statement with a *SUM*:

```
select sum(case when o.opendate is not null and o.orderdate is not null and o.closedate is null and o.canceldate is null
             then 1 else 0
        end) as OrderCount
```

You should then remove the conditions from the `where` clause.

Comment: I think you need to SUM() it as well to get the count.  Nice answer though!

Comment: What is the then 1 else 0? Would the sum go in place of the count?

Comment: The `Then 1 Else 0` returns a 1 or a 0 for each row depending on the `Case` criteria, the `Sum` that wraps the `Case` statement adds these values to get the total number of rows that apply to the `Case` criteria.

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want with a having clause.

```
select s.ZipCode, count(o.[OrderID]) orderCount, b.Longitude, b.Latitude, b.ordering 
from ZipCodeServiceAvailability s  
left join pdx_orders_view o on s.ZipCode = left(o.[ZipCode], 5)  
left join ZipCodeBoundaries b on s.ZipCode = b.ZipCode  
Where s.state = 'TX' and Ordering % 10 = 0 and 
     o.opendate is not null 
Group By s.ZipCode, IsServiced, b.Longitude, b.Latitude, b.Ordering  
Having count(o.[OrderID]) is not null
Order by s.ZipCode, b.Ordering
```